# Does a compiler manage CPU registers?

Tags: compiler-construction, cpu, cpu-registers

If not, can you explain what does the compiler in the image means?

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1q3ZrTdat0VFgg3sSsTxZRuQXS3ODUDKMzG5tSAt9bIM/edit

Answer (score 4):

The compiler [allocates architectural registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation), but is constrained by the [platform ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), which specifies what registers are used for parameter passing, which may be used freely, which must be saved before entering/leaving a function, etc.

This isn't the complete story, however, because the architectural registers (that you see used in assembly language, like `RAX`, `XMM0`, etc.) of most modern CPUs are themselves really a kind of abstraction. The *physical* registers in most CPUs are completely inaccessible to software of any kind, significantly outnumbering the visible architectural registers. The CPU itself decides how to assign these “secret” internal registers to the architectural registers that programmers and compilers deal with. The CPU can detect certain kinds of data dependencies in an instruction sequence and do things like [register renaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming) to resolve some of them, which supports [instruction-level parallelism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction-level_parallelism), for example.

Comment: ABIs often *allow* the compiler not to use the calling convention for *internal* functions for which the compiler can control how registers are used in the called function (if one can inline the function, changing the call interface is not a big deal). Following the ABI for internal functions may be convenient (and *recommended* by the ABI) but not necessarily *required*. For separately compiled code, the ABI avoids the need to extend the interface to provide per-function information (and simplifies compiling and probably debugging). (Just nitpicking)

Comment: You're correct, of course, but IMHO this is a subtlety that's perhaps a bit above the appropriate level for this particular question. TBH, I'm not sure I didn't go into too much detail already.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a phase called 'register allocation' in most compilers that compile to native code, in which the compiler decides which variables can go in which registers and how best to manage the register set for best performance. That's what the column in your picture is referring to.

I don't know why you think you need further confirmation, but here it is.

Answer (score 0):

The way you asked your question suggest that you actually believed otherwise, that compiler does not manage CPU registers.

To my knowledge compiler does use CPU registers to a detailed level, by generating instructions such as MOV R1, R2. Here even which registers are used are specified by generated instruction.

Comment: I am aware that, cpu registers can be manipulated by assembly language instructions.My doubt is whether a compiler can take complete control of cpu registers, like what goes in and out of the registers?

Comment: @uday I don't understand how you can possibly have any doubt about it. That's what the compiler *does.* It generates assembly instructions that move data into and out of registers. Among other things.